# How do I beautify the ticks on the x-Axis if the ticks are too close each other?

Tags: javascript, c3.js

As you can see the scale ticks on the x-Axis are overlapping each other:

[image]

Using `fit: true` doesn't change anything because it is default set to `true` already.

```
axis: {
  x: {
    tick: {
      fit: true
    }
  }
}
```

Using `count` is not good either, because when we zoom in to a certain area you don't see any scale ticks at all anymore.

```
axis: {
  x: {
    tick: {
      count: 5
    }
  }
}
```

Is it possible to change the number of ticks according to the zoom level? So that the zoomed in parts has always got the same amount of scale ticks?

Comment: Why did I got a downvote? IMO it's a valid and concrete question that fits very well in SO.

Answer (score 0):

```
axis: {
  x: {
    tick: {
      fit: true
    }
  }
}
```

http://c3js.org/reference.html#axis-x-tick-fit

---

Or you can just set a max tick count:

```
axis: {
  x: {
    tick: {
      count: 5
    }
  }
}
```

http://c3js.org/reference.html#axis-x-tick-count

Comment: According to the image, this is already being done. "fit" just means show labels only for the x-values. Setting it to false sets the labels at regular intervals.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhat broad question, no?

You could stagger them, putting some labels higher and some labels lower, and testing for overlap with bounding boxes.

Or you could rotate your labels: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4403522